# Why I can't rename style resources with dot notation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, refactoring, rename

I have this ongoing problem that I cannot rename any style resource written in a dot notation. I tried to search for solutions online but could not find any clue as of why may this be happening.

[style resource parent - rename option appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lUjm.png)

[style resource child - rename option does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUPKj.png)

Earlier this year I was using Android Studio 3.6 I believe and renaming was working fine, I then proceeded to update Android Studio to 4.1 and the renaming problem appeared. Since I wasn't able to find a solution I removed Android Studio completely and re-installed it on my computer (macOS).
Sadly the problem is still here, so I truly don't know what to do or what could be causing this.

Here is some info about the AS I'm using:

*Build: AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, 202011050241*
*AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Mac OS X(x86_64) v10.15.7*
*AS: 4.1.1; Kotlin plugin: 1.4.21-release-Studio4.1-1; Android Gradle Plugin: 4.1.0; Gradle: 6.5;*